# Git through a Proxy. What is causing the 407 error when cloning?

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to use Git through a proxy. I've tried setting parameters 'git config --global' in a lot of ways but always without success when cloning repositories.

I did:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://DOMAIN\\\username:password@10.0.2.42:8080
git config --global http.sslverify false
git clone http://github.com/project/project.git
```

And I got:

```
$ git clone http://github.com/project/project.git folder
Cloning into 'folder'...
error: The requested URL returned error: 407 while accessing http://github.com/project/project.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

So, how can I debug this or enable logging in Git to discover why I'm still getting the 407 error? Is there some parameter in Git to verbosely show what is happening to catch the right point where the error is occurring?

Comment: why are there three backslashes between your domain and your username?

Comment: Are you behind a ntlm proxy ? And is it that you are cloning on a linux box ?  If it is NTLM based authentication, just updating the .gitconfig or setting git values won't work :( . You may have to get CNTLM on your linux box which uses NTLM authetication. All I had to do was point my CNTLM to my network's proxy server and then point my software update manager(like yum,apt-get or ssh) to the local proxy. In case of git operations like clone,pull the http.proxy was my locally configured proxy with the local server.

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar problem trying to `git push` from a Git Bash client in Windows.
I fixed it just by **browsing to the site** using Chrome.
Then I came back to Git Bash and it worked right away

For clarity, my GIT repository URL looks like `http://me@me.git.cloudforge.com/myproject.git`
And I browsed to `http://www.cloudforge.com`

My understanding is that it forces the proxy to resolve this domain.

Comment: This is it! The random behavour I've seen in the past is finally explained. Thanks!

Comment: Plus one, dopeness.

Answer (score 7):

You can enable trace logging to get more information about what Git is doing. Following is an example:

```
GIT_TRACE=$HOME/trace.log git co master
```

You must use absolute paths if you want to send output to a file. Otherwise, use true or 1 to send output to standard error; e.g. `GIT_TRACE=1`.

Answer (score 6):

If you're already behind a proxy and getting this error, you will have to clear `http.proxy` *and* `https.proxy`:
`git config --global --unset http.proxy`
`git config --global --unset https.proxy`

Answer (score 3):

I think that you should start from the HTTP error: [HTTP 407 error explained](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E407.html).
And from that you can arrive at the answer: [proxy error issue](http://www.wetware.co.nz/2010/03/cant-access-github-behind-proxy-or-firewall/). Hope that helps.

Comment: Of course I tried Google =]. And as I configured the proxy, it shouldn't throw this error 407. I just want to discover if there are more parameters to be set.

Comment: I see. Did the issue I linked help? Because I had a problem like this once and it solved it.

Comment: Not helped too much... I use Win7 at work. I'm trying to clone with the Github HTTP url.

Comment: Maybe a silly question but: did you add github to the firewall exception list in win7?

Comment: I will write here if I can dig up something.

Comment: Thanks... I don't know whats happening. If I can access github site through the proxy I think git repositories could be accessed through the proxy too using HTTP.

Comment: The answer should contain the actual response to the question and not just links to external sites.

Comment: (>.<) The wetware.co.nz link is blocked by the corporate proxy I'm behind ⸮

Answer (score 2):

The following solved the problem for me

1. Rightclick on the git folder-> TortoiseGit->Settings->Network
2. Enable Proxy Server and input proxy, port, user, password

Answer (score 2):

If you are inside a corporate firewall and you are using windows git bash then:

Open global gitconfig file, usually this will be under C:\Users\USER_NAME.gitconfig and add the below lines if not exists.

```
[http]
proxy = http://USER_NAME:PASSWORD@PROXY_URL:PROXY_PORT
sslverify = false
[https]
proxy = http://USER_NAME:PASSWORD@PROXY_URL:PROXY_PORT
sslverify = false
```

Make sure your password does not have '@' character.
If you still have the problem and you are using proxy url instead IP then:
Open command - 'Windows Key+R' and type cmd then hit enter
execute the command:

> nslookup PROXY_URL

This will give some ip addresses. Try these ip addresses in .giconfig instead of PROXY_URL.

Answer (score 2):

This works for users on a domain and behind proxy with authentication and HTTPS inspection.
Use the following where the %5c is used instead of "\". 
ie. DOMAIN%5cusername@proxy:port

Open GIT config in editor by entering below command:

```
git config --global -e
```

Add/update following sections and save:

```
[http]
    proxy = http://domain%5cusername:password@proxy:port
    sslVerify = false
[https]
    proxy = http://domain%5cusername:password@proxy:port
    sslVerify = false
```

Answer (score 1):

This error may occur if proxy credentials are given, but invalid. In my case, it was an old password.

Comment: This is the least technical solution, and solved my problem too!

Answer (score 1):

I copied the http proxy section of my .gitconfig to https:

```
[http]
        proxy = http://user:pass@ip_or_host:port
[https]
        proxy = http://user:pass@ip_or_host:port
```

I put an incorrect password in the http proxy just to check, and it was ignored, so it's the https section that was missing for me.

Strangely, on another day that didn't work.  I don't know if I'm going crazy or if there's another step I forgot.  In today's case, this method of setting the proxy worked (with a cleared .gitconfig) from the command line:

```
HTTPS_PROXY="http://user:pass@ip_or_host:port/" git clone --progress -v "https://github.com/repo" local_folder
```

Notes:

1. If you're on a domain you might need to use the syntax `DOMAIN\user`.
2. This didn't work for TortoiseGit, but worked in gitbash on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Your proxy could also be set as an environment variable. Check if your environment has any of the env variables http_proxy or https_proxy set up and unset them.

Using command prompt

```
# Linux
export http://user:pass@ip_or_host:port
export http://user:pass@ip_or_host:port

# Windows
set HTTP_PROXY = http://user:pass@ip_or_host:port 
set HTTPS_PROXY = http://user:pass@ip_or_host:port
```

change Manually

- Right click on my computer
- select properties
- advanced system settings    advanced->system variables ->add

Answer (score 0):

Note that for any Git between 2.8 (February 2016, five years after the OP's question) and Git 2.13 (Q2 2017), an invalid proxy configuration would be *silently* ignored (not even a 407)

See [commit ae51d91](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ae51d91105981888f58ad21825b4ef0c540032e3), [commit 5741508](https://github.com/git/git/commit/57415089bd33575bcb7e134ddb2e1eacee3dfaca) (11 Apr 2017) by [Sergey Ryazanov (`acteek`)](https://github.com/acteek).
Helped-by: [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6b51cb6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6b51cb61812c11915dbcc1d6daeee60ac77297de), 24 Apr 2017)</sup>

> ### http: fix the silent ignoring of proxy misconfiguraion
>
> Earlier, the whole `http.proxy` option string was passed to `curl` without
>   any preprocessing so `curl` could complain about the invalid proxy
>   configuration.
>
> After the [commit 372370f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/372370f1675c2b935fb703665358dd5567641107) ("`http`: use credential API to handle proxy
>   authentication", 2016-01-26), if the user specified an invalid HTTP
>   proxy option in the configuration, then the option parsing silently
>   fails and NULL will be passed to curl as a proxy.
>   This forces `curl` to fall back to detecting the proxy configuration from the environment, causing the `http.proxy` option ignoring.
>
> Fix this issue by checking the proxy option parsing result. If parsing
>   failed then print an error message and die.
>   Such behaviour allows the
>   user to quickly figure the proxy misconfiguration and correct it.