# Cloning repository from Github to windows

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

Im using TortoiseGit and MsysGit in my Windows 7. I need to clone repository from github to my desktop. I did right click ->Git Clone->https://github.com/username/sample.git.I get the response as:

```
Cloning into 'D:\repo\sample'...
error: The requested URL returned error: 407 while accessing https://github.com/TruMobi/sample.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I had done the proxy settings in TortoiseGit.
Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561671? See my [answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29552646/1089267) about https proxy.

Answer (score 6):

HTTP 407 is indicates you need an HTTP Proxy Username/Password configured. I can't help you with what your proxy server is, or the credential to use it - but I'd check with the network folks wherever you're at.

You can do this with `git config` command.

```
$ git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
```

I'm not certain if TortoiseGit has a UI to set this, but it most likely does.  It will undoubtedly respect the underlying git CLI setting, so I'd go with that just to be sure.

Also, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734518/how-to-set-up-git-to-get-through-a-proxy) for more discussion.

Comment: as per ur instruction i had done the changes. Now im getting new error.  Cloning into 'D:\repo\sample'...
error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed while accessing https://github.com/username/sample.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed

Comment: Looks like you have a self signed certificate.  Try this now:  `git config --global http.sslVerify false`

Comment: again facing same error The requested URL returned error: 407 while accessing https://github.com/TruMobi/sample.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed

Comment: when i give my userid and password in abovw comment. It throws an eror:    Cloning into 'D:\repo\trumobi-pim-apps-android'...
error: Failure when receiving data from the peer while accessing http://github.com/TruMobi/trumobi-pim-apps-android.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed