# Git Bash on windows 7 behind proxy no longer working

Tags: windows, git, github

I'm on a windows 7, 32 bit box, and working behind a proxy. I just upgraded my git client (Git Bash) to `Git-1.8.3-preview20130601`, and all of the sudden, I'm getting the following error whenever I try to push/pull:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/User/simple_timesheets.git/: 
Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after Connect
```

I was able to do this just fine before upgrading, and even when I tried to revert back to the last version that I think I had, I still get the error. When I run `git config -l`, it lists out the following variables (among others):

```
user.name=MyName
user.email=My@email.com
http.proxy=http://user:password@server:port
core.autocrlf=true
https.proxy=http://user:password@server:port
http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

What's odd is that I seem to be able to use the `Git Bash` client to curl just fine

```
curl finance.yahoo.com --proxy http://user:password@server:port
```

and can even curl into a dummy https site I set up on my computer:

```
curl https://localhost:3000 --insecure
```

Any ideas what I'm missing? Thanks

---

EDIT:

I could be wrong, but I think there might be an issue with curl in version 1.8.3. I uninstalled all git related applications I could think of on my computer, and installed `Git-1.8.0-preview20121022`, ran a pull on a repo and was successful.

For giggles, I uninstalled the working version, and kept the cert file; then reinstalled version 1.8.3 to see if this didn't have anything to do with it, but I got the same error I was originally trying to resolve.

Also, after re-installing version 1.8.0, I tried to curl an https website (gmail), with the following command: `curl https://www.gmail.com --proxy http://user:pass@server:port`, which was successful. When I did this under 1.8.3, I got an error about code 407. The version switch seems like it solved this.

Comment: I just tried running the following: `curl https://www.gmail.com --proxy http://user:password@server:port > gmail.html`, and it gave the following: `curl: (56) Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561671? See my [answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29552646/1089267) about https proxy.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue resolved it by using two proxy filters:

"--proxy or -x" and "--proxy-user".

```
curl -x http://proxyserverurl:port --proxy-user username:password -L http://url
```

Though what you have tried is also not wrong but might not be compatible with your curl version.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Exporting the environment variables `https_proxy` and `http_proxy` resolved the issue. So I ended up adding the following lines to the `.bashrc` file in the home directory:

```
# Configure proxy settings
export https_proxy='http://myproxy.example.com:8086/' 
export http_proxy='http://myproxy.example.com:8086/'
```