# Git clone throwing 407 errors

Tags: git, version-control, proxy, atlassian-sourcetree, git-clone

While cloning a git repository using command line or sourcetree throwing following error:

fatal: unable to access 'https://....xyz.git'. The requested URL returned error: 407

I think it's a proxy issue and did following things too.

```
1) Added http_proxy and https_proxy environmental variables
2) Updated git global http_proxy and https_proxy settings
3) Added GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1 to environmental variables
4) Configured openssl
```

Any idea why i'm getting this error?

Thaks in Advance.

Comment: It's a proxy authentication issue. When you configured your git proxy, did you try to also set a valid username,password? (It's an insecure setup though). Like what's mentioned [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/SourceTree-questions/using-proxies-with-SourceTree/qaq-p/356325) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24907140/git-returns-http-error-407-from-proxy-after-connect).