# Unknown SSL protocol error in connection when git clone

Tags: git, ssl, curl, proxy, openssl

I have to access internet via a proxy, so have following configure in my environment:

```
export https_proxy=https://proxy.xxx.xxx:xxx
```

But when I clone code from github(or anyother git repo) via 'https' link, I got error:

```
sunyi-ubuntu# git clone https://github.com/git/git.git
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/git/git.git/': Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:443
```

**But, the strange is that it could work so long as I ran a `curl` right before `git clone` like following:**

```
sunyi-unbunt:~# git clone https://github.com/git/git.git
Cloning into 'git'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/git/git.git/': Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:443
sunyi-ubuntu:~# curl https://github.com/git/git.git >& /dev/null
sunyi-ubuntu:~# git clone https://github.com/git/git.git
Cloning into 'git'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 138, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (138/138), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (74/74), done.
Receiving objects:   0% (1/271365)
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3
I installed libcurl4-openssl-dev
I built and installed the latest git source code.
And Following is the log when I `export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1`

```
Cloning into 'git'...
* Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
*   Trying 10.239.4.80...
* Connected to proxy.xxx.xxx (10.239.4.80) port xxx (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to github.com:443
> CONNECT github.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: github.com:443
User-Agent: git/2.22.0.545.g9c9b961
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

< HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
< Proxy-Authenticate: NEGOTIATE
< Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM
< Proxy-Authenticate: BASIC realm="CORP_AD"
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Proxy-Connection: close
< Connection: close
< Content-Length: 849
<
* Ignore 849 bytes of response-body
* Connect me again please
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:443
* Closing connection 0
* Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Hostname proxy.xxx.xxx was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 10.239.4.80...
* Connected to proxy.xxx.xxx (10.239.4.80) port 914 (#1)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to github.com:443
> CONNECT github.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: github.com:443
User-Agent: git/2.22.0.545.g9c9b961
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

< HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
< Proxy-Authenticate: NEGOTIATE
* gss_init_sec_context() failed: : SPNEGO cannot find mechanisms to negotiate
< Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM
< Proxy-Authenticate: BASIC realm="CORP_AD"
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Proxy-Connection: close
< Connection: close
< Content-Length: 849
<
* Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT
* Closing connection 1
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/git/git.git/': Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to
 github.com:443
```

========Updated========

[Git through a Proxy. What is causing the 407 error when cloning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561671/git-through-a-proxy-what-is-causing-the-407-error-when-cloning)

I have tried almost each options mentioned on above page, no one worked. 
But I just found a workaround that `git` would work well right after running a `curl`, no matter what kind of parameter given to the curl. 
So following alias always works well for me:
`alias git='curl u >& /dev/null & git'`
But I still curious the root cause of this issue!

Comment: HTTP/1.1 407 **Proxy Authentication Required**

Comment: Hi @phd , yes. But that was the question, why did git complain it?
I found a similar issue the 2nd answer on page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561671/git-through-a-proxy-what-is-causing-the-407-error-when-cloning)
```
I fixed it just by browsing to the site using Chrome.
Then I came back to Git Bash and it worked right away

For clarity, my GIT repository URL looks like http://me@me.git.cloudforge.com/myproject.git
And I browsed to http://www.cloudforge.com
```